# Function to extract pattern from string, but including brackets

Tags: r, text, pattern-matching

I'm trying to extract the pattern from the string (different statuses divided by | symbol) and using the function *str_extract*:

```
> str_extract('Wrong DATA (3)', "Wrong DATA (3)|No answer (1)|No answer (2)|No answer (3)|No answer (6)|No answer (7)")
> [1] NA
```

But it gives me NA. How can I find the patterns that include brackets?

P.S. I can’t just delete the brackets, because in my task there are repeating patterns with and without brackets, but they need to be separated into different groups

Comment: Escape the brackets using \

Comment: in your case you need to use `Wrong DATA \\(3\\)|No answer \\([12367]\\)"` as the pattern

Comment: Thank You! The "\\" works, if I put it only to the string(not the first - pattern)